# always show notifications in activity overview (gnome shell 3.10)

Tags: gnome, notification, activities-overview

I want the notification bar to be always shown when I use activity overview. In some version of Gnome Shell (maybe 3.2 or 3.4) it was by default so I was wondering if it can be done in Gnome Shell 3.10?

P.S.
Why? I really don't want to be constantly checking notifications bar if I missed something. I would see if there is notifications when I am using activity overview to switch programs.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the only way to always see notifications in Activities overview with GNOME 3.10 is by writing an extension or patching GNOME Shell.
There is a bug registered in GNOME bugzilla about this problem "Message Tray isn't easily discoverable (isn't shown in Activities Overview)", see: 
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=719649

Also I've found another old bugreport, related to this problem: 
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641723

Also I've found one extension which helps access messaging tray in GNOME Shell: 
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/634/tray-pressure-visualizer/

Currently only high mouse pressure activates notification area/messaging tray. Low pressure does nothing. Pressure is defined by the number of pixels past the edge of the screen. If pressure is set to 250px, you need to move your mouse 250px past the edge to activate it. This setting can be tweaked in /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/layout.js:

// The message tray takes this much pressure
// in the pressure barrier at once to release it.
const MESSAGE_TRAY_PRESSURE_THRESHOLD = 250; // pixels
const MESSAGE_TRAY_PRESSURE_TIMEOUT = 1000; // ms

For example, to have the message tray appear instantaneously set MESSAGE_TRAY_PRESSURE_THRESHOLD to 0.

Comment: Wow that pressure thing is daft! If you use an absolute graphics tablet you can't apply pressure! Thanks!